# Firebase realtime database returning null value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
dbRef1 = database.getReference("/parkingLocation/marinParking/max");
dbRef2 = database.getReference("/parkingLocation/marinParking/curr");

...

ValueEventListener changeListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG,"In change listener");
        String firstValue = dataSnapshot.child(currUser.getUid()).child("parkingLocation").child("marinParking").child("max").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG,"The value of max is " + firstValue);
        String secondValue = dataSnapshot.child(currUser.getUid()).child("parkingLocation").child("marinParking").child("curr").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG,"The value of current is" + secondValue);
        Toast.makeText(MarinParkingActivity.this,firstValue,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        maxTextView.setText(firstValue);
        currTextView.setText(secondValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        notifyUser("Database Error " + databaseError.toException());
    }
};
```

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase realtime database. I am using the above code to get the data from database, but I am receiving null value.

I am getting the following Log

2020-01-31 18:28:29.831 28878-28878/com.example.parkings D/MarinParking: In change listener
2020-01-31 18:28:29.832 28878-28878/com.example.parkings D/MarinParking: The value of max is null
2020-01-31 18:28:29.832 28878-28878/com.example.parkings D/MarinParking: The value of current isnull
2020-01-31 18:28:30.256 28878-28878/com.example.parkings D/MarinParking: In change listener
2020-01-31 18:28:30.258 28878-28878/com.example.parkings D/MarinParking: The value of max is null
2020-01-31 18:28:30.259 28878-28878/com.example.parkings D/MarinParking: The value of current isnull

And this is my database:

[image: And this is my database]

Comment: can you show your full code? where did you applied addValueEventListener?

Comment: can you post your dbRef2 initialization?

Comment: WHEN I CLICKED MY BUTTON TO SEE THE VALUE I CALL addValueEventListener

Comment: dbRef1 = database.getReference("/parkingLocation/marinParking/max");
        dbRef2 = database.getReference("/parkingLocation/marinParking/curr");

Comment: I got your problem, I will post the answer

Comment: Please **edit** your question to show the code that calls `addValueEventListener` too. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it contains great guidance that maximizes the chances of getting help quickly here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
       String firstValue = dataSnapshot.child(currUser.getUid()).child("parkingLocation").child("marinParking").child("max").getValue(String.class);
       String secondValue = dataSnapshot.child(currUser.getUid()).child("parkingLocation").child("marinParking").child("curr").getValue(String.class);
```

to

```
    String firstValue = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    String secondValue = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

---

Because you already gave the location path here.

```
        dbRef1 = database.getReference("/parkingLocation/marinParking/max");
        dbRef2 = database.getReference("/parkingLocation/marinParking/curr");
```

According to your current code (you posted on comment), use separate ValueEventListener for each dbRef. You can't get both results in a single ValueEventListener.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
        String firstValue = dataSnapshot.child(currUser.getUid()).child("parkingLocation").child("marinParking").child("max").getValue(String.class);

        String secondValue = dataSnapshot.child(currUser.getUid()).child("parkingLocation").child("marinParking").child("curr").getValue(String.class);
```

into this:

```
        String firstValue = dataSnapshot.child("parkingLocation").child("marinParking").child("max").getValue(String.class);

        String secondValue = dataSnapshot.child("parkingLocation").child("marinParking").child("curr").getValue(String.class);
```

There is no `uid` in your database.

Comment: Sir I tried this way also but the result is same i get null value

Comment: the reference is wrong, are you doing dbRef1.addValueEventListener(changeListener)??

Comment: dbref1 should just be equal to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` and then when u retrieve u access the child as in this answer